# How to gather received buffers in socket programming (TCP/IP) in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, io, tcpclient

I am using the server-client model for communicating with a hardware board using socket programing.

I receive data from board using "read()" method of "NetworkStream" class which reads a buffer with specified maximum size and returns the length of valid data in buffer. I have considered the maximum size of buffer with a enough big number.

The board sends a set of messages every 100ms. Each message consists a 2-byte constant header and a variable number of bytes as its data after the header bytes.

The problem is that I do not receive the messages one by one! Instead, I receive a buffer may contains 2 or 3 messages or one message is scattered between two buffer.

Currently, I am using a DFA which gather the content of messages using the constant header bytes (We do not know the length of messages, we just know the header bytes) but the problem is that the data bytes may contains the header bytes randomly !!

Is there any efficient way to gather the bytes of each message from buffers using any specific stream or class? How can I overcome to this problem?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an additional buffer component between your consumer DFA and the socket client.

Whenever data is avaliable from the `NetworkStream` the buffer component will read it and append it to its own private buffer, incrementing an "available bytes" counter. The buffer component needs to expose at least the following functionality to its users:

1. a `BytesAvailable` property -- this returns the value of the counter
2. a `PeekBytes(int count)` method -- this returns the first `count` bytes of the buffer, if that much is available at least, and does not modify the counter or the buffer
3. a `ReadBytes(int count)` method -- as above, but it decrements the counter by `count` and removes the bytes read from the buffer so that subsequent `PeekBytes` calls will never read them again

Keep in mind that you don't need to be able to service an arbitrarily high `count` parameter; it is enough if you can service a `count` as long as the longest message it would be possible to receive at all times.

Obviously the buffer component needs to keep some kind of data structure that allows "wrapping around" of some kind; you might want to look into a circular (ring) buffer implementation, or you can just use two fixed buffers of size `N` where `N` is the length of the longest message and switch from one to the other as they become full. You should be careful so that you stop pulling in data from the `NetworkStream` if your buffers become full and only continue pulling after the DFA has called `ReadBytes` to free up some buffer space.

Whenever your DFA needs to read data, it will first ask your buffer stage how much data it has accumulated and then proceed accordingly. It would look something like this:

```
if BytesAvailable < 2
    return; // no header to read, cannot do anything

// peek at the header -- do not remove it from the buffer!
header = PeekBytes(2);

// calculate the full message length based on the header
// if this is not possible from just the header, you might want to do this
// iteratively, or you might want to change the header so that it is possible
length = X; 

if BytesAvailable < X
    return; // no full message to read, cannot continue

header = ReadBytes(2); // to remove it from the buffer
message = ReadBytes(X); // remove the whole message as well
```

This way your DFA will only ever deal with whole messages.